# How to trim out "Date" from Date/Time field in Salesforce?

Tags: datetime, time

I have a Date/Time field (call it Field A) that gets populated by an external system, i'd like to create another field that trims/extracts the Time value from Field A. I want to do this to use a certain Time as a trigger point for a workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TIMEVALUE(Field_A) to convert DateTime to Time

> Converting Between Date/Time and Time
>
> The TIMEVALUE() function returns a Time data type value in
> “HH:MM:SS.MS” (hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds) format using a
> 24-hour clock. Numerical H/M/S/MS values and the HOUR(), MINUTE(),
> SECONDS(), and MILLISECONDS() functions are valid parameters for
> TIMEVALUE().
>
> Use the TIMEVALUE(value) function to return the Time value of a
> Date/Time type, text, merge field or expression. For example, extract
> the time from a ClosedDate Date/Time value with TIMEVALUE(ClosedDate).

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5)